# cropping the part of image which is inside the square box in android

Tags: android

In my app I want to crop the image exactly same as in the screenshot.How to achieve this? I want to crop the image which is is inside the square and also I want to give height and width of my own.The other part of the image which is laying outside of the box should be blurred as shown in the picture.Can any one tell,how can I do this?[image]

Comment: use this library it help you https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

Comment: @sushildlh That will resize right? I mean the height and width of that box.I want to crop as we are using in Facebook. The size of the box is not resizing there and the part of image inside the box only will be cropped.

Comment: How can I implement this one in my app.I did not get any answer

Comment: go through this ,it give you step by step procedure http://www.elluminati.in/how-to-crop-images-in-android/  **AND** if you need the library let me know ??

Comment: @sushildlh This is the normal way.I dont want crop in this way.If u didn't understand my question,Please once check with facebook profile picture updating. I want to implement same thing in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are lots of library for image croping plz check this link and use according to your requirements:

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45

Comment: I have used https://github.com/oginotihiro/cropview But there image is moving.I want to move the square instead of that.

Comment: In that corners are re sizable .So I did not use that one.I want fixed one where user of this app,shouldn't resize the 4 corners.

Comment: In my screen shot that square box with blue color is not resizing.I want in that way.